# Avro Schema not fitting classes

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

i'm new to Avro and already know it's a fantastic lib, i would like some help to make me fit a Avro file to a specific class.
I'm not sure why i placed the first record entry, it is my first schema and i tried out by merging (with a little thinking) some schema i saw on sof/ internet. 
The class is:

```
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata
class ParsedData extends Serializable {
    var extractedText: String = _
    var outlinks: Set[String] = Set.empty[String]
    var metadata: Metadata = new Metadata()
    var headers: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map.empty
}
```

and my avro schema related to it is the following

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "AvroSparkler",
    "namespace": "edu.usc.irds.sparkler.avro",
    "fields": [
    {
        "name": "ParsedDataKafka",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "ParsedDataKafka",
            "namespace": "edu.usc.irds.sparkler.avro",
            "fields": [
            {
                "name": "outlinks",
                "type": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "metadata",
                    "type": {
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "metadata",
                        "namespace": "edu.usc.irds.sparkler.avro",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "metadata",
                                "type": {
                                    "type":"map",
                                    "values": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "headers",
                    "type": {
                        "type": "map",
                        "values": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I don't need the extractedText for Kafka producer so i don't put it on the schema

Comment: Thanks for providing test data, but could you check again whether all the parentheses are actually balanced? What's with that last trailing closing brace that is hanging outside of the code block?

Comment: I suggest trying to use the Avro4s library

Comment: Thanks you for replying, i update the schema on parenthsesis and bracket, it's generated well. Well i'll take a look at Avro4s library

Comment: could you explain better what is the problem or what you are trying to achieve?